# generate dsym file error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, build

My build got this error:

```
GenerateDSYMFile /data/rdm/projects/14060/build/Developer/JietuMac.app.dSYM /data/rdm/projects/14060/build/Developer/JietuMac.app/Contents/MacOS/JietuMac
cd /data/rdm/projects/14060/QQ4Mac/JietuMac
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil /data/rdm/projects/14060/build/Developer/JietuMac.app/Contents/MacOS/JietuMac -o /data/rdm/projects/14060/build/Developer/JietuMac.app.dSYM
/Users/rdm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/62N1HANH19UZ/Foundation-IL1BEAVQDALK.pcm: Clang modules are expected to have exactly 1 compile unit.
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil failed with exit code 1
```

I deleted the derivedData, then build succeed. But it needs me to delete the derivedData every time before build.

Does anybody knows how to reset the location? or solve the problem. Thanks very much.